# how to transfer file from ubuntu desktop to hortonworks sandbox

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

I have a jar file in local desktop in my ubuntu. Would like to transfer to Horton works sandbox running in vm player .In windows we have winscp to perform it.I don't know how to do it in ubuntu. Could you please help.

Comment: Filezilla is an alternative to Winscp. Works the exact same

Comment: You can start simple python server from file path and access any where

Comment: Run in Ubuntu's terminal: `scp /tmp/your_file horton-sandbox-ip:/tmp/your_file` change the paths with your owns

Answer (score 0):

HortonWorks made it simple for you by using the HDFS file view and then uploading it from Ambari. It's easier.

Or like it said in the comments

```
      scp your_file user@ip_address:/file/path
```